# Bean validation for Integer field

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I am trying to have constraint validation on the field, which must reject if the input is not an integer.

```
public class ClientTO {
       private Integer phone_num; //
}
```

I tried:

1) `@Digits` - It does not validate if input is integer or not as you could see the type mismatch exception is still thrown.

2) My custom validation - which seems to not work on `Integer` fields

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer.
```

My custom validation class:

```
public class X_CVAImpl implements ConstraintValidator<X_CustomValidatorAnnotation,String>{  
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean val_d;
        if (value.matches("[0-9]+") && value.length() ==10) {
            val_d=true;
        }else {
            val_d=false;            
        }
        return val_d;
    }
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: Seems that you declared a validator for `String` fields, but you annotated an `Integer` field with it. Beside that, why didn't you just apply the `@Pattern` constraint on a string field?

Comment: I am trying to construct entity on `ClientTO`  to put it into MVC model, I did not want use string field as I wanted the entity properties of proper type so there wouldn't be any issues when put it into MVC model. trying to work on validator for `Integer` as you suggested.

Comment: Using an integer field simply means that type checking would fail **before** bean validation if the wrong data is used. If you have to use `Integer`, then the only constraint you need is perhaps `@NotNull`, and whatever you use for serialization will take care of making sure that the data type is valid.

Comment: got it, thanks. Could you put it into answer.

Answer (score 7):

[@Digits will only work for primitive types](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Bean_Validation_Cheat_Sheet#.40Digits). 
So if you change your entity to the following, your validation should kick in.

```
public class ClientTO {
   @Digits(integer=10, fraction=0)
   private int phone_num; // Constraint: phone_num can only be 10 digits long or less
   ...
}
```

Having that said, I believe that you should use a string to validate a phone number.

```
public class ClientTO {
   @Size(min=10, max=10)
   @Pattern(regexp="(^[0-9]{10})")
   private String phone_num; // Constraint: phone_num would match 10 digits number
   ...
}
```